# Ag Grid + How to Make a particular column from a particular row editable or Non Editable Dynamically

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Ag Grid Enterprise version. I have below requirements.

1) I have 3 columns. All the 3 columns are drop down fields. Based on the selection of the value in first column, I have to make second and third column in a particular row to be editable or Non Editable dynamically.

2) An object which contains the list of all the visible rows from the grid. Even if i add a new row, I should be getting that new row as part of the list

Can anyone please let me know how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first requirement: Each colDef has a property colDef.editable which can be a boolean or, in your case, a callback function:

```
colDef.editable = function(params) {
   // params contains the following properties:
   // params.node
   // params.column
   // params.colDef

   return true; // apply your criteria based on params;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am using this approach suggested by you but it works only when the grid loads. I also need a similar functionality when a value is changed from a particular row.

Comment: Would you mind to have a look at this issue and address it ?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022346/angular-ag-grid-single-click-issue-with-ie-11?noredirect=1#comment98688411_56022346]

Answer (score -1):

Here I have considered a scenario of having a grid with two columns Option and Year which are dropdowns. Option dropdown contains values 1,2 and 3 and Year dropdown years from 1990-1995. When value 1 is selected from Option dropdown, it will not allow you to change the year.

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  ag-grid Example
</div>
<app-grid></app-grid>
```

**grid.component.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**grid.component.cs**

Column definitions of the grid is set by making the **editable: true** and for each column definition, separate components are bind as cell editor and cell renderer.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { OptionsCellRendererComponent } from './options-cell-renderer/options-cell-renderer.component';
import { OptionsCellEditorComponent } from './options-cell-editor/options-cell-editor.component';
import { YearCellRendererComponent } from './year-cell-renderer/year-cell-renderer.component';
import { YearCellEditorComponent } from './year-cell-editor/year-cell-editor.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html'
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions = {
    } as GridOptions;
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.setData();
  }

  setData() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.getColumnDefinitions());
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.getData());
  }

  getColumnDefinitions(): any {
    return [
      {
        field: 'option',
        headerName: 'Option',
        cellRendererFramework: OptionsCellRendererComponent,
        cellEditorFramework: OptionsCellEditorComponent,
        editable: true,
        singleClickEdit: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'year',
        headerName: 'Year',
        cellRendererFramework: YearCellRendererComponent,
        cellEditorFramework: YearCellEditorComponent,
        editable: true,
        singleClickEdit: true,
      },
    ]
  }

  getData(): any {
    return [
      {
        option: '1',
        year: 1990
      },
      {
        option: '2',
        year: 1991
      }
    ];
  }

}
```

**options-cell-editor.component.html**

Cell editor component for Option column with a dropdown of values 1,2,3

```
<div>
  <select style="height: 20px; width: 180px;" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <option value=1> 1</option>
    <option value=2> 2</option>
    <option value=3> 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**options-cell-editor.component.ts**

when option value is changed, pass it to the option-cell-renderer through getValue()

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-options-cell-editor',
  templateUrl: './options-cell-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./options-cell-editor.component.css']
})
export class OptionsCellEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp {
  selectedOption = 0;

  getValue(): number {
    return this.selectedOption;
  }

  isPopup?(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.selectedOption = params.value;
  }
}
```

**options-cell-renderer.component.html**

Showcase the value of the option

```
<div>{{option}}</div>
```

**options-cell-renderer.component.ts**

params.value will pass the value bind to this column from the grid rowdata. In this case the value of the 'option' property and bind it to the UI.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-options-cell-renderer',
  templateUrl: './options-cell-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./options-cell-renderer.component.css']
})
export class OptionsCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any;
  option: string;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.option = params.value;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  constructor() { }    
}
```

**year-cell-editor.component.html**

Cell editor component for Year column with a dropdown of years 1990-1995

```
<div>
  <select style="height: 20px; width: 180px;" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear">
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**year-cell-editor.component.ts**

user is allowed to change the year if the option selected is not 1. This is handled by
isCancelBeforeStart method.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-year-cell-editor',
  templateUrl: './year-cell-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./year-cell-editor.component.css']
})
export class YearCellEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp {
  selectedYear: number;
  params: any;

  constructor() { }

  getValue() {
    return this.selectedYear;
  }

  isPopup?(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  isCancelBeforeStart?(): boolean {
    return this.params.data.option === '1';
  }

  agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.selectedYear = params.value;
  }
}
```

**year-cell-renderer.component.html**

Showcase the value of the selected year

```
<div>{{year}}</div>
```

**year-cell-renderer.component.ts**

params.value will pass the value bind to this column from the grid rowdata. In this case the value of the 'year' property and bind it to the UI.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-year-cell-renderer',
  templateUrl: './year-cell-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./year-cell-renderer.component.css']
})
export class YearCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  year: number;

  constructor() { }

  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  agInit(params): void {
    this.year = params.value;
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

Register the grid custom cell components

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GridComponent } from './grid/grid.component';
import { OptionsCellEditorComponent } from './grid/options-cell-editor/options-cell-editor.component';
import { OptionsCellRendererComponent } from './grid/options-cell-renderer/options-cell-renderer.component';
import { YearCellEditorComponent } from './grid/year-cell-editor/year-cell-editor.component';
import { YearCellRendererComponent } from './grid/year-cell-renderer/year-cell-renderer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GridComponent,
    OptionsCellRendererComponent,
    OptionsCellEditorComponent,
    YearCellEditorComponent,
    YearCellRendererComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      OptionsCellEditorComponent,
      OptionsCellRendererComponent,
      YearCellEditorComponent,
      YearCellRendererComponent
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your valuable time to respond to my query. I will see if I can make the changes like you mentioned.

Comment: Hope my answer helped

Comment: Would you mind to have a look at this issue and address it ?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022346/angular-ag-grid-single-click-issue-with-ie-11?noredirect=1#comment98688411_56022346]